# eBay Trading API LeaveFeedbackCall

Tags: vb.net, ebay-api, ebay-net-sdk

I am attempting to set seller feedback through the eBay Trading API, `LeaveFeedbackCall`. I am using the .NET SDK and am having difficulty assigning the feedback details. In the API description this is an array `SelerItemRatingDetailsArray` that holds `ItemRatingDetails` with two items, `Rating (Int)` and `RatingDetail (FeedbackRatingDetailCodeType)`. The line of code I am using that is throwing an error follows.

```
apicall.SellerItemRatingDetailArrayList.Item("Communication").Rating = iCommunication.
```

`iCommunication` is an integer variable holding a value between 0 and 4.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please copy the error message and append it to the bottom of your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this code instead.

```
ItemRatingDetailsType itemRateing = new ItemRatingDetailsType();
itemRateing.RatingDetail = FeedbackRatingDetailCodeType.Communication;
itemRateing.Rateing = iCommunication;
apicall.SellerItemRatingDetailArrayList.Add( itemRateing);
```

C# syntax.
Basically you can not use the SellerItemRatingDetailArrayList like you were trying to.

Link: [DetailedSellerRatings](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/WebHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?context=eBay_XML_API&topic=DetailedSellerRatings) and [LeaveFeedbackCallMembers](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/WindowsSDK/docs/LibRef/eBay.Service.Call.LeaveFeedbackCallMembers.html)